# Ceph: too many PGs per OSD

Tags: ceph

I configured Ceph with the recommended values (using a formula from the docs).  I have 3 OSDs, and my config (which I've put on the monitor node and all 3 OSDs) includes this:

```
osd pool default size = 2
osd pool default min size = 1
osd pool default pg num = 150
osd pool default pgp num = 150
```

When I run `ceph status` I get:

```
 health HEALTH_WARN
        too many PGs per OSD (1042 > max 300)
```

This is confusing for two reasons.  First, because the recommended formula did not satisfy Ceph.  Second, and most puzzling, is that it says I have 1042 PGs per OSD, when my configuration says 150.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many pools do you have?

Comment: @NoahWatkins - This is all new to me, I hope this is what you're asking for.  `ceph osd lspools` returns: `0 rbd,1 .rgw.root,2 default.rgw.control,3 default.rgw.data.root,4 default.rgw.gc,5 default.rgw.log,6 default.rgw.users.uid,7 default.rgw.users.keys,8 default.rgw.meta,9 default.rgw.users.swift,10 default.rgw.buckets.index,11 default.rgw.buckets.data,` - so 12 pools?

Comment: each pool has a set of placement groups. so if each pool has 100 PGs, then a cluster with 12 pools will have 1200 PGs. This might be useful: http://ceph.com/pgcalc/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before setting PG count you need to know 3 things.

**1. Number of OSD**

```
ceph osd ls

Sample Output:
 0
 1
 2
 
 Here Total number of osd is three.
```

**2. Number of Pools**

`ceph osd pool ls` or `rados lspools`

```
Sample Output:
  rbd
  images
  vms
  volumes
  backups
     
Here Total number of pool is five.
```

**3. Replication Count**

```
ceph osd dump | grep repli

Sample Output:
 pool 0 'rbd' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_ruleset 0 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 64 pgp_num 64 last_change 38 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0
 pool 1 'images' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_ruleset 1 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 30 pgp_num 30 last_change 40 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0
 pool 2 'vms' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_ruleset 1 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 30 pgp_num 30 last_change 42 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0
 pool 3 'volumes' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_ruleset 1 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 30 pgp_num 30 last_change 36 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0
 pool 4 'backups' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_ruleset 1 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 30 pgp_num 30 last_change 44 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0

You can see each pool has replication count two.
```

Now Let get into calculation

## Calculations:

#### Total PGs Calculation:

```
Total PGs = (Total_number_of_OSD * 100) / max_replication_count

This result must be rounded up to the nearest power of 2.
```

**Example:**

No of OSD: 3 
No of Replication Count: 2

Total PGs = (3 * 100) / 2 = 150.  Nearest Power of 150 to 2 is 256.

So Maximum Recommended PGs is 256

You can set PG for every Pool

#### Total PGs per pool Calculation:

```
Total PGs = ((Total_number_of_OSD * 100) / max_replication_count) / pool count

This result must be rounded up to the nearest power of 2.
```

**Example:**

No of OSD: 3 
No of Replication Count: 2 
No of pools: 5

Total PGs = ((3 * 100) / 2 ) / 5 = 150 / 5 = 30 .  Nearest Power of 30 to 2 is 32.

So Total No of PGs per pool is 32.

#### Power of 2 Table:

```
2^0     1
2^1     2
2^2     4
2^3     8
2^4     16
2^5     32
2^6     64
2^7     128
2^8     256
2^9     512
2^10    1024
```

## Useful Commands

```
ceph osd pool create <pool-name> <pg-number> <pgp-number> - To create a new pool

ceph osd pool get <pool-name> pg_num - To get number of PG in a pool

ceph osd pool get <pool-name> pgp_num - To get number of PGP in a pool

ceph osd pool set <pool-name> pg_num <number> - To increase number of PG in a pool

ceph osd pool set <pool-name> pgp_num <number> - To increase number of PGP in a pool

*usually pg and pgp number is same
```

Answer (score 4):

How I fixed it in 12.2.4 luminous:

Too many PGs per OSD (380 > max 200) may lead you to many blocking requests.

First you need to set:

```
[global]

mon_max_pg_per_osd = 800  # < depends on you amount of PGs
osd max pg per osd hard ratio = 10 # < default is 2, try to set at least 5. It will be
mon allow pool delete = true # without it you can't remove a pool
```

Then restart all MONs and OSDs, one by one.

Check the value:

```
ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.ceph2.asok config get  mon_max_pg_per_osd
ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-osd.3.asok config get osd_max_pg_per_osd_hard_ratio
```

Now look here:

```
rados lspools
ceph osd pool get .users.email pg_num
```

In my case by default `pg_num` was 128 or something like that (my cluster is 4 years old, it was a lot of upgrades a lot of changes). You can reduce it like that.

Be careful:

```
ceph osd pool create .users.email.new 8
rados cppool .users.email default.rgw.lc.new
ceph osd pool delete .users.email .users.email --yes-i-really-really-mean-it
ceph osd pool rename .users.email.new .users.email
ceph osd pool application enable .users.email rgw
```

If it wasn't enough, try to find another pool you can cut.