# Is it ever possible to reduce pg_num for specific pool

Tags: bigdata, ceph

It's sad that I found it's not allowed by `ceph` cli to decrease the value of `pg_num` for a specific `pool`.

`ceph osd pool set .rgw.root pg_num 32`

The error is shown:
`Error EEXIST: specified pg_num 32 <= current 128`

The tutorial from [placement-groups](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/rados/operations/placement-groups/) is about to tell me what is it and how to set the best value of it. But there is seldom any tutorial about how to reduce the `pg_num` without re-installing ceph or delete the pool firstly, like [ceph-reduce-the-pg-number-on-a-pool](https://swamireddy.wordpress.com/2017/04/18/ceph-reduce-the-pg-number-on-a-pool/).

The existed SO thread [ceph-too-many-pgs-per-osd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771273/ceph-too-many-pgs-per-osd) shows us how to decide the best value. If I met the issue, how can I recover from the mess?

If it's not easy to reduce the value pg_num, what's the story behind it? Why doesn't `ceph` expose the interface to reduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nautilus](https://ceph.com/rados/new-in-nautilus-pg-merging-and-autotuning/) version allows `pg_num` changes without restrictions (and  `pg_autoscale`).
If you want to increase/reduce `pg_num`/`pgp_num` values without having to create, copy & rename pools (as suggested on your link), the best option is to [upgrade](https://ceph.io/releases/v14-2-0-nautilus-released/#upgrading-from-mimic-or-luminous) to Nautilus.

Comment: Checked the updated just now, looks like a significant modification. Thanks for this answer.